# Select largest date common to mutliple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table like below, with a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT(user, date)`, how do I select the `max(date)` common to all users in a list `(1, 2)`?

```
ID | date     | user | value
-----------------------------
1  | 2016-5-1 | 1    | a
2  | 2016-5-1 | 2    | b
3  | 2016-5-3 | 2    | c
4  | 2015-5-4 | 1    | d
```

So with `WHERE user IN (1, 2)`, the query should return `2016-5-1`.

I have two working versions below so far, but neither seems really clean. Are there any better/more generic/more flexible ways to achieve what I want? Note I only need this to work in PostgreSQL.

a) relying on the length of the `sensor` list:

```
SELECT a.date FROM 
    (SELECT date, COUNT(date) 
        FROM mytable WHERE sensor_id IN (8, 9)
        GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC) a
    WHERE a.count = 2 LIMIT 1;
```

b) with separate subqueries:

```
SELECT i.date
    FROM (SELECT date FROM mytable WHERE user_id=1) i
    JOIN (SELECT date FROM mytable WHERE user_id=2) j
ON i.date = j.date ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Ordering by date descending and selected only 1 record seems the best way to me.

Comment: Is this for two users only or for an arbitrary number of users?

Comment: @dnoeth arbitrary number

Comment: @klin's answer works for any number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select date
from mytable
where user_id in (1,2)
group by date
having count(date) = 2
order by date desc
limit 1;
```

A number in `having` must be equal to a cardinality of list in `where`.

Comment: Why did you change Standard SQL `MAX` to to a proprietary `LIMIT`?

Comment: `max()` could show more than one row because of `group by date` (you can check it if more than one date is common for given users). As an alternative `max()` can be used in an outer query.

Comment: Ops, my fault, you're correct, in fact MAX should result in an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are fine, but each can be tweaked to be a bit better.

The first one does not require a subquery:

```
SELECT date
FROM mytable
WHERE sensor_id IN (8, 9)
GROUP BY date
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

MySQL materializes subqueries, which increases overhead.  In addition, the `ORDER BY` in the subquery is just a waste of characters in the query -- it either does an unnecessary sort or MySQL ignores it.

The second version should be written like this:

```
SELECT i.date
FROM mytable i JOIN
     mytable j
     ON i.date = j.date AND i.sensor_id = 8 AND j.sensor_id = 9
ORDER BY i.date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Once again, the subqueries impede performance.  In this case, they might prevent the use of an index for the `JOIN` as well as incurring the overhead of materialization.

Either version is a fine way to express the logic.  I find the first method more generalizable.  If performance is an issue, then you should try both versions on your data and your system to see which works better.